# permission denied when read file from server android

Tags: java, android

am trying to check if a file exist on server but the only that i get back is 
Error opening trace file. Permission denied (13)
the code is the below

```
 public static boolean exists(String URLName){
        try {
          Log.i("TAG", "tag "+URLName);
            HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
          // note : you may also need
          //        HttpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)
          HttpURLConnection con =
             (HttpURLConnection) new URL(URLName).openConnection();
          con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
          Log.i("TAG", "return code "+ con.getResponseCode());
          return (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           return false;
        }
      }
```

Also on the manifest i have include the code

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

can someone help me how i can solve it?

Comment: Can you show the stack trace?

Comment: i don't knwo if is the certain error that you want?
01-09 04:28:24.787: E/cutils-trace(15921): Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
on the code it get pass from the first log.i but not from the second log.i

Comment: do i have to add any other permission on the manifest beside the ones that i have insert?

Comment: it throws exception in which is null on line
 catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           return false;
        }
do i have sert something wrong and thats why it don't fine the file?

Comment: `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); return false; }` is not one line. We'll need the full stacktrace to give any assistance.